# 7- OG 'og_users_roles' table doesn't seem to update on Group creation

Tags: 7, organic-groups

I recently noticed that when a user of my site create a new group, the `og_users_roles` table do not get updated. Witch basicly means that unless the Group creator goes to the "members management" interface to give himself "Group admin", the newly created group do not have an administrator. So `og_get_users_by_roles` return empty when searching for the "Group admin" rid.

Is this normal? If so how would i go to give a group creator the "Group admin" role by default on group creation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed that by hooking on node creation and updating the table myself. 
I'll let the thread open in case anyone have a better solution.